# Get the path of a JSF project?

Tags: jsf, path

I'm working on a JSF application and I want to launch a script located in my Web projet, how can I make this without beginning the path from c:....., is there a way to get the root path of a JSF application?

Comment: What do you want to achieve - lookup a resource file? And from where? Javascript? Serverside?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a script that is running in your webpage, then `/` is the root of your application.

Comment: OK Thank you, I have found it : FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath()

Answer (score 0):

```
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext(); 

String webContentRoot = ec.getRealPath("/")
```

As shown above, first initialise the ExternalContext object. Then call the object's `getRealPath("/")` method to get the root path of your application.

Comment: Not sure what was the question, but this answer helped me developing with Eclipse where I could get a real path of the folder Eclipse and Tomcat put my project to. It was _C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.35\wtpwebapps\MyProjcet_.